# $http promise taking very long to resolve in Safari

Tags: javascript, angularjs, safari

This code works in every browser besides Safari (I haven't tested in IE).

I am using a ui-router resolve to call my API and pass data to my controllers:

```
.state('gallery.views', {
            url: "/{gallery:shades-of-gray|color}",
            views: {
                'left@gallery': {
                    templateUrl: 'components/gallery/partials/gallery-slick.html',
                    controller: 'SliderController'
                },
                'right@gallery': {
                    templateUrl: 'components/gallery/partials/gallery-img.html',
                    controller: 'GalleryImgController'
                }
            },
            resolve: {
                apiFactory: 'apiFactory',
                drawings: function(apiFactory, $stateParams){
                    console.log(Date.now() + " in resolve!");
                    var param = $stateParams.gallery === 'color' ? 'color' : 'bw';
                    return apiFactory.getImageUrls(param)
                        .then(function(result){
                            console.log(Date.now() + " resolved!");
                            return result.data.gallery;
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

Here are the important parts of the two controllers:

```
.controller('SliderController', function($scope, drawings){
    $scope.drawings = drawings;
    ...
}

.controller('GalleryImgController', function($scope, drawings){
    $scope.currentDrawing = drawings[0];
    ...
}
```

And my API factory:

```
apiFactory.getImageUrls = function(gallery){
    console.log(Date.now() + " in getImageUrls with gallery " + gallery);
    if (gallery === undefined)
        var gallery = 'all'

    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: API_URL + '/drawings/' + gallery
    });
};
```

This code executes perfectly in Firefox and Chrome:

```
1451686464870 in resolve! gallery.js:26:1
1451686464870 in getImageUrls with gallery bw api.js:69:1
1451686465891 resolved!
```

However, in Safari, I wait **120 seconds** between when I make the $http request and when the promise is resolved. I know that the issue isn't server-side, since I log the request (which is also 120 seconds from when it's resolved).

```
1451686493868 in resolve!
1451686493868 in getImageUrls with gallery bw
1451686614736 resolved!
```

Here is my error:

```
Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'drawings')
http://localhost:3000/components/gallery/gallery.js:52:34
invoke@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angularjs/angular.js:4478:22
instantiate@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angularjs/angular.js:4486:33
http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angularjs/angular.js:9151:39
http://localhost:3000/bower_components/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:23334
invokeLinkFn@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angularjs/angular.js:8789:15
nodeLinkFn@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angularjs/angular.js:8289:23
compositeLinkFn@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angularjs/angular.js:7680:23
publicLinkFn@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angularjs/angular.js:7555:45
k@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:22679
http://localhost:3000/bower_components/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:23001
invokeLinkFn@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angularjs/angular.js:8789:15
nodeLinkFn@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angularjs/angular.js:8289:23
compositeLinkFn@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angularjs/angular.js:7680:23
publicLinkFn@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angularjs/angular.js:7555:45
http://localhost:3000/bower_components/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:23479
invokeLinkFn@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angularjs/angular.js:8789:15
nodeLinkFn@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angularjs/angular.js:8289:23
compositeLinkFn@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angularjs/angular.js:7680:23
publicLinkFn@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angularjs/angular.js:7555:45
k@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:22679
http://localhost:3000/bower_components/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:22946
$broadcast@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angularjs/angular.js:16311:33
http://localhost:3000/bower_components/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:18565
processQueue@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angularjs/angular.js:14745:30
http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angularjs/angular.js:14761:39
$eval@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angularjs/angular.js:15989:28
$digest@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angularjs/angular.js:15800:36
$apply@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angularjs/angular.js:16097:31
done@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angularjs/angular.js:10546:53
completeRequest@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angularjs/angular.js:10744:15
requestLoaded@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angularjs/angular.js:10685:24
(anonymous function)angular.js:12476
(anonymous function)angular.js:9245
invokeLinkFnangular.js:8790
nodeLinkFnangular.js:8288
compositeLinkFnangular.js:7679
publicLinkFnangular.js:7554
kangular-ui-router.min.js:6:22679
(anonymous function)angular-ui-router.min.js:6:23001
invokeLinkFnangular.js:8788
nodeLinkFnangular.js:8288
compositeLinkFnangular.js:7679
publicLinkFnangular.js:7554
(anonymous function)angular-ui-router.min.js:6:23479
invokeLinkFnangular.js:8788
nodeLinkFnangular.js:8288
compositeLinkFnangular.js:7679
publicLinkFnangular.js:7554
kangular-ui-router.min.js:6:22679
(anonymous function)angular-ui-router.min.js:6:22946
$broadcastangular.js:16310
(anonymous function)angular-ui-router.min.js:6:18565
processQueueangular.js:14744
(anonymous function)angular.js:14760
$evalangular.js:15988
$digestangular.js:15799
$applyangular.js:16096
doneangular.js:10545
completeRequestangular.js:10743
requestLoadedangular.js:10684
```

Line 52 is in `GalleryImgController`.

Comment: You may **think** the problem isn't server side, but it could be. What does the server side code look like

Comment: 120 seconds seems like a 2 minute HTTP timeout - check if `result.data` is null

Comment: @JaromandaX you were correct. The issue was with this line in my Express server: `res.sendStatus(200).json(ret)`, which should have been `res.status(200).json(ret)`. `res.sendStatus()` appends the HTTP headers to the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay here is the response I get from the server on Safari (after 120 seconds):

[image]

I `console.log(drawings)` in my controller and I still get an `undefined`, even though the data is there. Could it be some sort of JSON parsing error? It looks like `result.data` has HTTP headers in it.

EDIT: So now I'm trying to parse the JSON but get the error `Error: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "HTTP"`. Doesn't explain the lag but does explain the `undefined`.

Here is `result.data`

[image]

## **Solution**

The issue was on the server (obviously).

I simply changed the following line from:

```
res.sendStatus(200).json(ret);
```

to

```
res.status(200).json(ret);
```

Which can really be simplified to `res.json(ret)`.

From the [Express docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfEXg.png) for `res.sendStatus()`:

*Set the response HTTP status code to `statusCode` and send its string representation as the response body.*

Contrast this with `res.status()`:

*Use this method to set the HTTP status for the response.*

I thought I was doing the latter with the former. However Firefox and Chrome allowed me to get away with this I'm not entirely sure, but I'm certainly happy that Safari brought this error to my attention.